# How to configure PyQt4 for Python 3 eclipse in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, pyqt

I installed PyQt4 with synaptic.

I'm using Python3 so I need to configure the path for PyQt4 in eclipse, but it seems synaptic only installed PyQt4 for python 2 since I only found relative files and folders under python 2.6 and 2.7.

So how can I make **PyQt4** to work with **Python 3** and **eclipse** ?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**：

I tried to configure it following this post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10914908#post10914908

But after following all the instructions without any error occurs in the way, I get error from running this code in python 3.2:

```
>>> import PyQt4
```

The error message is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PyQt4
```

But the strange thing is that the same code results NO error in python 2.7 (I have both 2.7 and 3.2 installed on my machine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be possible. The source sits at [Riverbank's site](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download). However, compiling it might not be a one-line deal but should work. Have a look at a [thread over at the ubuntuforum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1427918) where eranga1988 had a similar problem.

Further down in that thread CoBrA2168 seems to give a solution:

- download both SIP and PyQt4 from the official website
- install qmake, python3.1-dev, gcc-c++ (for the g++ command), and the libqt4-dev.
- then the compilation worked along the following lines

  > `python3.1 configure.py`
  >
  > `make`
  >
  > `sudo make install`
- note that some had to provide qmake's location to the call to python above:

  > `python configure.py -q /usr/lib/qt4/bin/qmake`

  where they got the path to qmake from `locate qmake`

You might have to tune this to your version of Python 3. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Install Python3 bindings for Qt4. In Ubuntu 12.04 and later open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt4
```